# How to programmatically edit all hyperlinks in a Word document?

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

Is there a macro, VBA code or VBScript that I can write to edit the urls of all the hyperlinks in my Word document?  Either Word 97-2003 or docx format.

Comment: What sort of edits do you want to make?  Do you want to cycle through each hyperlink or make the same change to each?

Comment: Basically I want to do a replace on each hyperlink.  The file server name changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Dim doc As Document
Dim link, i
'Loop through all open documents.
For Each doc In Application.Documents
    'Loop through all hyperlinks.
    For i = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count
        'If the hyperlink matches.
        If LCase(doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address) = "http://www.yahoo.com/" Then
            'Change the links address.
            doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address = "http://www.google.com/"
            'Change the links display text if desired.
            doc.Hyperlinks(i).TextToDisplay = "Changed to Google"
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Here is a link to all the [Hyperlink Methods and Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.hyperlink_members.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't work with images with hyperlinks =/ Do you know how to get those?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me immensely.  User had opened Word Docs containing hyperlinks through her mapped drive instead of going in the long way through network.  Hundreds of docs will be saved!

I used mid() function:

```
Sub FixMyHyperlink()

    Dim doc As Document
    Dim link, i

    'Loop through all open documents.
    For Each doc In Application.Documents
        'Loop through all hyperlinks.
        For i = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count
            'If the hyperlink matches.
            If LCase(doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address) Like "*partOfHyperlinkHere*" Then
                'Change the links address. Used wildcards (*) on either side.
                doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address = Mid(doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address, 70,20)        '
                'Change the links display text if desired.
                'doc.Hyperlinks(i).TextToDisplay = "Oatmeal Chocolate Chip Cookies"
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tester for the solution, used it for a quick replace:

```
Sub ReplaceLinks()

Dim doc As Document
Dim link, i

'Loop through all open documents.
For Each doc In Application.Documents
    'Loop through all hyperlinks.
    For i = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count

        'Update old bookmarks to https
        doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address = Replace(doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address, "gopher:", "https://")

   Next
Next
End Sub
```