# Combining fields with a url

Tags: vba, ms-word

Currently I am building a Word document which is being filled by custom fields from a third party with the actual data.

The proces on filling the document is as follow:

> 1. From third party program generate document -> 2. Word opens, I can execute
>      my VBA code -> 3. document closes again -> 4. document opens and is being
>      filled with the data from third party program -> 5. document gets exported to Outlook.

So far this works fine, I can mimic the third party their Word fields with VBA code.

Now I would like to use some of this data to generate a unique url. The url would look as follow: http://example.com?q1=field1&q2=field2 (in this example the only thing in the document also).

What I am trying to do now is to replace 'field1' or 'field2' with the actual necessary Word field (dynamically). This doesn't seem to work for URL's (works fine seperatly). The code would be executed at the second part of the proces.

To replace certain tags with fields I use the following code, I was hoping that it would also work for URLs but that doesnt seem to be the case.

```
item would have as input:
item(0) = "field1" - tag name, 
item(1) = "Example" - First part of the field, 
item(2) = "<<contract_example>>" - Second part of the field

Private Sub TranslateItem(item() As String)
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory 
    Selection.find.Text = item(0) 
    Dim holder As Boolean
    holder = True
    Do While holder
        Dim tempholder As Boolean
        tempholder = Selection.find.Execute
        If tempholder Then
            Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:=item(1) & item(2), PreserveFormatting:=False 'add field
        Else
            holder = False
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

This code doesn't seem to replace the actual part of the URL but just the text. I came across this ([How to programmatically edit all hyperlinks in a Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355266/how-to-programmatically-edit-all-hyperlinks-in-a-word-document)) link on how to edit a url, but I have no clue on how to search and replace the tag and add a field in that example.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over all hyperlinks in the document and then modify their properties as you need it:

```
Sub ModifyHyperlinks()
    Dim link As Hyperlink
    For Each link In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        link.Address = Replace(link.Address, "q1=", "q1=field1")
        link.Address = Replace(link.Address, "q2=", "q2=field2")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I fixed it today. I ran into the issue whenever the fields are put into the hyperlinks they do not generate the value, so I can only take the result. So what I did to solve this is build the hyperlink in the document as text with the fields and then it works fine when I copy that to my actual link. It is weird that it doesn't directly in the fields itself. Thank you though!

Comment: @usselite: Just saying: even if you don't award the bounty before it expires, you will lose the rep anyway.